# sqlite trouble reading

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.3

I have a favDatabase which read a data from my database:

.h

```
@interface favDatabase : NSObject {

UIWindow *window;
UINavigationController *navigationController;

NSString *databaseName;
NSString *databasePath;

NSMutableArray *idSPBData;
}
```

.m

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Setup some globals
    databaseName = @"usualBike.sql";

    // Get the path to the documents directory and append the databaseName
    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];

    // Execute the "checkAndCreateDatabase" function
    [self checkAndCreateDatabase];

    // Query the database for all favorites
    [self getFavorites];

    // Configure and show the window
    [window addSubview:[navigationController view]];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

Now in my favoriteView, I try to read the data:

```
favDatabase *fav = (favDatabase *)[UIApplication sharedApplication];

return fav.idSPBData.count;
```

but, it crashes:

```
 2012-09-03 13:44:13.692 usualBike[1857:11603] -[UIApplication idSPBData]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6e2f5a0
 2012-09-03 13:44:13.693 usualBike[1857:11603] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIApplication idSPBData]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6e2f5a0'
```

I'm using Xcode 4.3, is this a release problem?

Comment: It's absolutely not an issue with Xcode. The shared application is an instance of UIApplication, not your favDatabase class. UIApplication obviously has no method names idSBData.

Comment: idSPBData is a NSMutableArray from favDatabase (its in .h)

Comment: Yes, but the shared application instance is _not_ an instance of favDatabase. It's an instance if UIApplication.

Comment: You can't just point at a stone, call it an airplane and say its broken when it won't fly you to your favorite vacation destination.

Answer (score 0):

Keep a property variable holding your database in your delegate class, then call:

```
favDatabase *fav = (favDatabase *)((AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].myFavDatabase);
```

assuming `AppDelegate` is your main delegate.

Another approach is to make your DB instance a singleton:

```
+(favDatabase *)sharedManager{
    static dispatch_once_t pred;
    static favDatabase *shared = nil;

    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
        shared = [[favDatabase alloc] init];
    });
    return shared;
}
```

Using:

```
@interface favDatabase : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (nonatomic) favDatabase  *myFavDatabase;
```

Comment: Is this what you mean? @interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>{

    favDatabase *fav;

}

Comment: I modified the answer accordingly (and changed the variable name). Try to use upperCase letter for the first letter of your classes to avoid confusion with variables.